# Proving (((finset.range 50).erase 0).erase 1).sum id = (finset.range 50).sum id - 1

Tags: lean3

I'm trying to prove the statement `(((finset.range 50).erase 0).erase 1).sum id = (finset.range 50).sum id - 1` in Lean 3. The mathlib theorem `finset.sum_erase_eq_sub` seems helpful, but I can't get Lean to apply it. Here is a failing example:

```
import data.finset.basic
import data.finset.interval
import algebra.big_operators.basic

theorem range :
  (((finset.range 50).erase 0).erase 1).sum id = (finset.range 50).sum id - 1 :=
begin  
  rw finset.sum_erase_eq_sub _,
end
```

Does anyone know how to prove this simple statement?

Comment: Ah, I guess the problem with `finset.sum_erase_eq_sub` is that it only works for groups, while $\mathbb{N}$ is not a group. Does anyone know of another solution? Perhaps I should calculate the sum in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The issue likely comes from the fact that subtraction on $\mathbb{N}$ has a tricky behaviour, because it is truncated to 0, so it is not a real inverse to addition. Thus the theorem probably does not hold in all generality on $\mathbb{N}$ because of some corner case. So indeed you should probably calculate the sum in $\mathbb{Z}$, and then transfer the equality to $\mathbb{N}$ if you need to. Or you can look at the proof of `finset.sum_erase_eq_sub` and craft a version of it that works on $\mathbb{N}$, which will likely have some inequalities as side-conditions.